# Is there a way to add a page element to all unpublished pages?

Tags: theming

I am trying to add an "unpublished" graphic on all content that is unpublished so editors can clearly see that the page is unpublished, but I have about 15 different content types.

Is there a way I can add this to all content easily with twig templates or otherwise?

Comment: By default, Drupal adds a css class on the body (if I am not mistaken) indicating it is not published. In default themes, the page would then have a reddish hue behind the content so you knew it was unpublished. It is also visible from the edit form or content overview screen in the admin.

Comment: I managed to find that it is adding `note--unpublished` to some content types, is there a way to make it do it to all content types?

Comment: It would do that to all content types. That makes me believe there is something in your custom theme that may be altering this class list based on content types that are not receiving it?

Comment: I will do some more digging. Thanks

Comment: The *node--unpublished* CSS class is listed in [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/9.3.x), which means Drupal adds it independently from the used theme. If then a theme removes it from `attributes.class`, that is a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if (!$node->isPublished()) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'unpublished-class-for-node';
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah or `$variables['some_element'] = ['#markup' => '<h1>unpublished</h1>'];` and then in the node.html.twig put `{% if some_element %}{{ some_element }}{% endif %}`. Wondering if you could access the unpublished status maybe directly in the template as well. 